# Google Drive API - get unique list of files in folder

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm using the PHP beta library for Google drive. I've got a list of files in a folder, but it's duplicating the file names a bunch of times.

Here is my drive folder. You can see there are only 7 files:

[image]

But when I list using the library (titles only) I get this.

`Array[39]
0:"cantact"
1:"bsn"
2:"posh"
3:"posh"
4:"posh"
5:"postum"
6:"dynamite"
7:"dynamite"
8:"dynamite"
9:"dynamite"
10:"dynamite"
11:"dynamite"
12:"dynamite"
13:"dynamite"
14:"dynamite"
15:"dynamite"
16:"ecoamour"
17:"posh"
18:"ecoarmour"
19:"hex.pdf"
20:"hex"
21:"dynamite"
22:"earthtreks"
23:"dynamite"
24:"earthtreks"
25:"earthtreks"
26:"dynamite"
27:"dynamite"
28:"earthtreks"
29:"dynamite"
30:"dynamite"
31:"dynamite"
32:"dynamite"
33:"dynamite"
34:"evpro"
35:"evpro"
36:"evpro"
37:"Untitled"
38:"evpro"`

Obviously this is because of archived/revisions or something similar.  But how can I get a list of the files that mimics what I see in Drive like above?

```
<?php

require_once "/var/www/belts/modules/admin.php";
require_once "/var/www/api/googleDriveAPI.php";

$drive = new GoogleDrive();

// contracts folder
$folderId = "{{folder id}}";
// get file list
$files = $drive->service->files->listFiles([
    "q" => "'$folderId' in parents"
]);
// unique array of titles
$titles = [];
foreach ($files->getItems() as $file) {
    $titles[] = $file->title;
}
//$titles = array_unique($titles);

echo json_encode($titles);

?>
```

Comment: I've added the picture from the link

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Needed to add `and trashed=false` to the query